# SP2007: Outputting "Created by" in a Data View Sharepoint Control

Tags: sharepoint-2007, dataviewwebpart

I inserted a Data View Sharepoint Control to a custom layout page. The data source is a list in a sub-site. One of the things I wish to display is "Created By".

What I get is...

```
<nobr><span><A HREF="/Policies/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=628">George Carter</A><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/><a href='javascript:' onclick='IMNImageOnClick();return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='GCarter@choosemaryland.org' id='imn_445,type=smtp'/></a></span></nobr>
```

when all I want is...

George Carter

Any clue as to why it's including those HTML elements?

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I found a solution to my problem here:

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution to my problem here:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/unlocking-the-mysteries-of-data-view-web-part-xsl-tags-part-12-miscellaneous-person-or-group-columns.aspx

But I welcome any other comments, suggestions, etc.

Thanks.

"Have patience. All things are difficult before they become easy." Saadi